# Windows Phone 8 back button event (OnBackKeyPress) handling?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to make Windows Phone 8 back button event (OnBackKeyPress) by another method? I have been trying to call that event from outside button click or page initializer. but it gives an error?

```
OnBackKeyPress += new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs>(OnBackKeyPress);
```

> No overload for 'OnBackKeyPress' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just override the back key press event like below,

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   //Do your work here
   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this is the implementation:
/// <summary>
/// Called when the hardware Back button is pressed.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">Set e.Cancel to true to indicate that the request was handled by the application.</param>
protected virtual void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e);

so don't forget to set the cancel value before giving it to the base.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one

```
    public Page()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      BackKeyPress +=PageBackKeyPress;
    }

    void PageBackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
          // code
    }
```

Comment: Can't I use the Given Event Handler OnBackKeyPress ?

Comment: @gayan1991 then you can use OnBackKeyPress overriden method [look @ WinMobiler's answer].

Answer (score 2):

Just type "override" (without quotes) and then press space, all the overridden methods will appear, select the onBackKeyPress method.

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

    }
```

this method will appear, now u can write ur chunk of code inside.